# For what $n$ the set $\{\sin x, \cos x, (\sin x)^2, (\cos x)^2,..., (\sin x)^n, (\cos x)^n\}$ is linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Under what condition of $n$ the following set $\{\sin x, \cos x, \sin^2x, \cos^2x,..., \sin^nx, \cos^n x\}$ is linearly independent?
I tried to replace n=1,2,3 but I haven't get the general result. Could you please help me?

Comment: In which space? You probably need to consider a scalar product, orthogonality conditions etc...

Comment: If $n=1$ the set ${sin x , cos x }$ is linearly independant. For $n>1$ in the set the elements $sin^2x$ and $cos^2x$ are not lineary independents since $sin^2x +cos^2x = 1$

Comment: @JJacquelin: 1 is not in the previous set.

Comment: Ho! Of course !!! I delete my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can prove the set as linearly independent for $n\le3$, you can show the set is not linearly independent for $n>3$.  JJacquelin's comment gave me the idea.  We have

$$\cos^4x-\sin^4x=(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)$$
$$\cos^4x-\sin^4x-\cos^2x+\sin^2x=0$$

Comment: I got it. Thank you.